# SQLite Find Name where datetime is between start and end

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following table in my database, which represents the shifts of a working day.
When a new product is added to another table 'Products' I want to assign a shift to it based on the `start_timestamp`.

So when I insert into `Products` its takes `start_timestamp` and looks in table `ProductionPlan` and looks for a result (`ProductionPlan.name`) where it is between the start and end timestamp of that shift.
On that way I can assign a shift to the product.

I hope somebody can help me out with this!

**Table ProductionPlan**

| name | start_timestamp | end_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| shift 1 | 2021-05-10T07:00:00 | 2021-05-10T11:00:00 |
| shift 2 | 2021-05-10T11:00:00 | 2021-05-10T15:00:00 |
| shift 3 | 2021-05-10T15:00:00 | 2021-05-10T19:00:00 |
| shift 1 | 2021-05-11T07:00:00 | 2021-05-11T11:00:00 |
| shift 2 | 2021-05-11T11:00:00 | 2021-05-11T15:00:00 |
| shift 3 | 2021-05-11T15:00:00 | 2021-05-11T19:00:00 |

**Table Products**

| id | name | start_timestamp | end_timestamp | shift |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Schroef | 2021-05-10T08:09:05 | 2021-05-10T08:19:05 |  |
| 2 | Bout | 2021-05-10T08:20:08 | 2021-04-28T08:30:11 |  |
| 3 | Schroef | 2021-05-10T12:09:12 | 2021-04-28T12:30:15 |  |

[image]

I have the following code to insert into `Products`:

```py
    def insertNewProduct(self, log):
        """
        This function is used to insert a new product into the database.
        @param log : a  object to log
        @return None.
        """
        debug("Class: SQLite, function: insertNewProduct")
        self.__openDB()
        timestampStart = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(log.startTime)).isoformat()
        queryToExecute = "INSERT INTO Products (name, start_timestamp) VALUES('{0}','{1}')".format(log.summary,
                                                                                                   timestampStart)
        self.cur.execute(queryToExecute)
        self.__closeDB()
        return self.cur.lastrowid
```

It's just a simple `INSERT INTO` but I want to add a query or even extend this query to fill in the column shift.

Comment: can you show your python code that you are using to insert data?

Comment: If the shifts are the same every day, then it's silly to have a "shift table".  You can do that with a simple math.  The shift number is `(timestampStart.hour - 3) // 4`

Comment: @TimRoberts In this example the shifts are the same, but in reality, they can be configure in any way I want, the data is collected from a Google Calendar via a API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a SELECT inside an INSERT.

```
    queryToExecute = """INSERT INTO Products (name, start_timestamp, shift)
                        SELECT :1, :2, name FROM ProductionPlan pp
                        WHERE :2 BETWEEN pp.start_timestamp and pp.end_timestamp"""
    self.cur.execute(queryToExecute, (log.summary, timestampStart))
```

In above code I have used a parameterized query because I hate inserting parameters as strings inside a query. It was the cause of too many [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks...

Comment: Took me a while to figure it out! but it works great.
I will edit my query's so they don't have parameters in te string, thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: `INSERT INTO Products (name, start_timestamp, shift)
SELECT "name", '2021-05-17 08:05:00', name FROM ProPlan pp
WHERE STRFTIME('%H:%M:%S', '2021-05-17T08:05:00') BETWEEN pp.start_timestamp and pp.end_timestamp
`
I also added a `STRFTIME` part , this way the table `ProductionPlan ` only needs time not date.